# Use devise_invitable to send invitation upon creating new model record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-invitable

#### Non-technical Context

I'm working with an app that manages data for different companies.  For the purposes of this situation I have two models `User` and `Company`.  Often we set up a company for the user before they even have an account, we then create the user and give the login info to the appropriate party via some clunky means like a phone call.  We would like to send an invitation to the user upon creating a new company.

#### Technical Info

We are using devise for our user management and recently came across a [great little gem called devise_invitable.](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable)  Which sends out invitations through devise's mailer.

#### The Problem

While devise_invitable works really well for simply inviting a user, I can't figure out how to get it to send out an invitation using a controller (like the `companies_controller`) other than the `invitations_controller`.  **My key hangup is** that the invitable functionality seems to require us to either go through `invitations_controller` and its respective views or use its `User.invite!` method.  Both creates a user and sends an invitation.  This means that if I add User.invite! to the create method as shown below, I'll duplicate the user.

#### My Question

How can I both create a new company and invite a new user all within the `companies_controller`?  I've been creating users (just not inviting them) with the following methods.  If anyone knows how I should alter them to use the invitation functionality, I would really appreciate it.

**From `companies_controller`**

```
def new
    @company=Company.new
    @user=@company.user_companies.build.build_user
    @folder=@company.folders.build
    @stock=@company.stocks.build
    @stock.security_class="Common"
    @stock.security_series=""
end

def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)
    if @company.save
        redirect_to users_admin_path(@user), notice: "User successfuly created!"
    else
        redirect_to welcome_index_path
    end
end
```

Anyway, thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, figured it out (or at least figured one way out).  Basically I created a set of dummy variables in the `Company` model like so:

```
attr_accessor :user_email, :user_fname, :user_lname
```

Then I updated the controller as follows

```
def new
    @company=Company.new
    @folder=@company.folders.build
    @stock=@company.stocks.build
    @stock.security_class="Common"
    @stock.security_series=""
end

def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)
    if @company.save
        invitedUser=User.invite!(email: company_params[:user_email], fname: company_params[:user_fname], lname: company_params[:user_lname], invited_by: current_user)
        if invitedUser.save
            UserCompany.create(user: invitedUser, company: @company, company_role: "Owner")
            redirect_to companies_path, notice: "User successfuly created!"
        end
    else
        redirect_to welcome_index_path
    end
end
```

#### The key highlights were

1. to remove `@user=@company.user_companies.build.build_user` because I don't want to build the user, I want it to be created by the `invite!` method.
2. To use `User.invite!` to create the user and grab the necessary data out of the submitted form's parameters
3. To manually add a join record (because I have a many-to-many relation between `Company` and `User`).

That's it really.